# Error response from daemon: Unrecognised volume spec: file '\\.\pipe\docker_engine' cannot be mapped. Only directories can be mapped on this platform

Tags: docker, docker-compose, named-pipes, traefik, windows-container

I'm new to the docker. Any help and tips are welcome.

Environments:

- Windows: Windows 10 Pro 21H1
- Docker Desktop: 3.4

I can run hello work example without any issues. But seems like I can't use named piped, can't figure out what is the issue.

Some people mentioned named piped is only available for Windows server, but this blog (https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-windows-server-1709/)clearly mentioned Windows 10 is supported.

docker version output:

```
❯ docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.4
 Git commit:        f0df350
 Built:             Wed Jun  2 12:00:56 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.7
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       b0f5bc3
  Built:            Wed Jun  2 11:56:41 2021
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

YAML file:

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  traefik:
    isolation: ${TRAEFIK_ISOLATION}
    image: ${TRAEFIK_IMAGE}
    command:
      - "--ping"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false"
      - "--providers.file.directory=C:/etc/traefik/config/dynamic"
      - "--entryPoints.websecure.address=:443"
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "8079:8080"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "traefik", "healthcheck", "--ping"]
    volumes:
      - source: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
        target: \\.\pipe\docker_engine
        type: npipe
      - ./traefik:C:/etc/traefik
    depends_on:
      id:
        condition: service_healthy
      cm:
        condition: service_healthy
  .......
```

I can create the container if I removed the named pipe in volumes then I got different error:

```
time="2021-06-17T06:32:13+08:00" level=error msg="Provider connection error error during connect: This error may indicate that the docker daemon is not running.: Get \"http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version\": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified., retrying in 7.701954985s" providerName=docker
```

The rest of containers are running Okay.

docker compose up output:

```
❯ docker compose up
[+] Running 10/11
 - Network sitecore-xp0_default                     Created                                                        1.1s
 - Container sitecore-xp0_mssql_1                   Created                                                        0.5s
 - Container sitecore-xp0_solr_1                    Created                                                        0.5s
 - Container sitecore-xp0_id_1                      Created                                                        0.4s
 - Container sitecore-xp0_solr-init_1               Created                                                        0.3s
 - Container sitecore-xp0_xconnect_1                Created                                                        0.3s
 - Container sitecore-xp0_cortexprocessingworker_1  Created                                                        0.6s
 - Container sitecore-xp0_xdbautomationworker_1     Created                                                        0.6s
 - Container sitecore-xp0_xdbsearchworker_1         Created                                                        0.9s
 - Container sitecore-xp0_cm_1                      Created                                                        0.9s
 - Container sitecore-xp0_traefik_1                 Creating                                                       0.2s
Error response from daemon: Unrecognised volume spec: file '\\.\pipe\docker_engine' cannot be mapped. Only directories can be mapped on this platform
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error and the solutions for me was to add a \ to the end.

Ref: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/31522/11642

Answer (score 16):

This error occurs when using Docker Compose V2. Turn off the option in Docker Desktop settings or use the CLI command `docker-compose disable-v2`.